# How to addfields in MongoDB retrospectively

Tags: mongodb, mern

I have a schema that has a like array. This array stores all the people who have liked my post.
I just added a likeCount field as well but the likeCount fields default value is 0.
How can I create an addfields in mongoDB so that I can update the likeCount with the length of the like array?

I am on a MERN stack.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to update all the documents with the respective likeCount values the first time:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
 {
   $addFields: {
    likeCount: {
      $size: "$like"
     }
   }
 }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Every next time somebody or multiple people are added to the like array , you may set the likeCount with the $size or you may increase the count with $inc operation.

Afcourse as @Buzz pointed below it is best to leave the array count() in the read code since updating every time like count() it will be an expensive operation leading to performance implication under heavy load ...

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/knHBu7Ju_g0)

Comment: Agreed this is directly answering the OPs Q but this is not a road we should lead them down -- esp. since touching the `likes` array now demands change to a peer field.

Comment: I completely agree here with your remark  @Buzz Moschetti  , indeed , reducing write load in mongo is first priority in performance optimisation  so counting the array in the read code will be much less expensive then updating the document with the count value every time there is a like ... updating my answer additionally ...

Comment: Good answers guys! Really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a data structure like this:

```js
{
   postId: "post1",
   likes: [ "ID1", "ID2", "ID3" ]
}
```

There is almost no reason to add a `likeCount` field.  You should take the length of the `likes` array itself.  Some examples:

```js
db.foo.insert([
    {'post':"P1", likes: ["ID1","ID2","ID3"]},
    {'post':"P2", likes: ["ID1","ID2","ID3"]},
    {'post':"P3", likes: ["ID4","ID2","ID6","ID7"]}
]);

// Which post has the most likes?
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {N: {$size: "$likes"}}},
    {$sort: {"N":-1}}
    //, {$limit: 2}  // optionally limit to whatever                              
]);

// Is ID6 in likes?                                                               
// $match of a scalar to an input field ('likes') acts like                       
// $in for convenience:                                                           
db.foo.aggregate([  {$match: {'likes':'ID6'}}  ]);

// Is ID6 OR ID3 in likes?                                                        
db.foo.aggregate([  {$match: {'likes':{$in:['ID6','ID3']}}}  ]);

// Is ID2 AND ID7 in likes?                                                       
// This is a fancier way of doing set-to-set compares instead                     
// of a bunch of expression passed to $and:                                       
var targets = ['ID7','ID2'];
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {X: {$eq:[2, {$size:{$setIntersection: ['$likes', targets]}} ]} }}
]);

// Who likes the most across all posts?                                           
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$likes'},
    {$group: {_id: '$likes', N:{$sum:1}} },
    {$sort: {'N':-1}}
]);
```